# C#: Datagridview not displaying the data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on winforms application. On my form I simply drag and drop a DataGridView control and then set some of its properties using the properties window. Following is the code which I am using to populate my DataGridView. I wrote this code inside the constructor.

```
List<MyCustomClass> lst = new List<MyCustomClass>();
lst = LoadList(/*some params here*/);//now uptil this point everything works i.e the list contains values as desribed.
dataGridView1.DataSource = lst;
```

The problem is that when i run the program nothing is displayed in my DataGridView.

For more details following code represents the properties which I set using properties window

```
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 329);
        this.dataGridView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
        this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(334, 106);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Check the **AutoGenerateColumns** property, try setting it to true

Comment: why don't people see the tags before answering. This post has nothing to do with ASP.NET

Comment: @Jame did you check the property ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta Yes, but it doesn't work in my case. I add the following line
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
above this line:
dataGridView1.DataSource = lst;

Comment: @Jame: There must be something else in your code which is the culprit. I just tried simple form with datagridview and a custom class list and it works fine. You can check it with simple sample app.

Comment: are you sure the list is not empty

Comment: @Jame Did you check your class for the properties, can you post the code for the class ?

Comment: @jame: Did it work out ?

Comment: @ V4Vendetta
Yes i check my class, every thing is public and still its not working :(

Comment: I have written designer code in designer.cs but I missed to add the grid in control.   this.Controls.Add(this.dgData);

Answer (score 12):

I've got nearly the same thing today, the problem was that my clas had public fields, not properties, since i've changed them to public auto properties - worked well for me.

Comment: Had the same issue, I think the documentation from MS should highlight that it won't work with fields. Seems obvious after the fact as it would have to use reflection to get the fields but everything is easy afterwards.

Comment: I think Paul means Property.  Reflection only works with Properties.  Yes, MS is very unconscientious in their documentation that costs trillions of developer hours everyday in their ill-formed or undocumented products. If not cookiemonster's post, I would be going around loop forever.

Answer (score 8):

You have to create Data Columns for your datagrid. Make sure you also set 'DataPropertyName' property of each column with the respected DataSource item's property (i.e., property of 'MyCustomClass' class).

Comment: THANK YOU! I am new to C# and I keep forgetting properties are a thing. I was having this issue for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 7):

Add this code before assigning the DataSource and you should be fine

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

**EDIT**

Also check if you have public properties which would be used to display the contents of the Class as columns in the DataGridView

Comment: default value for AutoGenerateColumns is true only, if he hasn't touched it then there is no point of assigning true again.

Comment: @JPReddy Very true .. but its not mentioned whether he has changed its value or not

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had no getters to properties!

Answer (score 1):

When I'm binding in designer have the same problem. But if I'm binding in constructor it works well

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = personBindingSource;
personBindingSource.DataSource = persons;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact similar issue. This usually happens when your custom class has private properties due to which the Data Grid View is unable to view them. You will need to create properties on your custom class fields and make them public so that when you set your data source from the custom class list, the data is visible to the Data Grid View and the data can flow through.

Answer (score 0):

I am on VS2022 w/ VB .Net 7.
My situation was the number of rows matches the datasource, but nothing is displayed:
Here's my solution:

1. Go the Designer mode
2. Click on the **Edit Columns** (in the Property panel)
3. For each of the column, type in the column name in your data source in the **DataPropertyName**

Now, if you are like me, you have a ComboList is the generated during the program runtime, you will need to do this to assign the DataSource for your combo

```
'mstrCellList has been populated
'the bottomline is you have to convert to the ComboBoxColumn in order to 
'access the DataSource property
CType(vsFlexRouteStep.Columns(Cell), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource _
  = mstrCellList
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -9):

Put this at the end:

```
datagridview1.Databind();
```

This should do.

Comment: Winforms datagrid doesn't contain a method called Databind().